# Where to keep helpers code and types for Remix

Tags: typescript, routes, helper, directory-structure, remix

I'm new to Remix and beginning some development with it. Since all code in the `app` directory essentially behaves like a router, if I were to make a `helpers` folder in app along with helper functions inside (using TypeScript, .ts files), I wouldn't necessarily want that code exposed as a route.

I also want to have a folder or file for all my types.

So where do I put them, so they are not a route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh! Just realized that under `app` is the `routes` folder, hence I can place my helpers code and types under `app` but outside of routes and therefore achieve what I wanted.